# Meaning of "boot"

Tags: meaning

(I'm not a native speaker of English)

I found a word in a George Martin's novel, "The Sworn Sword". There, a prince proposes to help in a battle to come with his "boot".

Maybe he wants to provide warriors, maybe it's some adequate equipment?

Can the word *"boot"* mean "heritage"? Can it mean "armed forces"?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you provide the paragraph for us in which this word is used? And show what you have found in the dictionary and explain why it doesn't help you?

Comment: What @Brian said. OED has defn 7a *Help or deliverance from evil or peril; assistance, relief, remedy, rescue. Often in phr. **boot of bale;** cf. **bale** n.1 6   concr. A means or agent of help, relief, or remedy; also, a personal agent, a helper.* That's identified as ***archaic*** or ***obsolete***, but feasibly Martin used it deliberately in that sense. Or you might have mis-parsed something like *The prince is going to fight with us to boot* (i.e. ***also, as well***).

Comment: It's *intended* to be puzzling -- something the characters understand but readers do not. Keep reading!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the book with me anymore, so I can't show you the paragraph. I've search in some on line dictionaries, and I found (amoung others) the meaning "to be of help or advantage; avail". But in the text, "boot" was indeed a noun, not a verb or an adjective. But I very much appreciated the definition you've written down, and I think that the meaning "a personal agent, a helper" answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In that story, Egg has a ring proving he is the nephew of the King (or some such relation).  That ring is hidden in his boot.  So when Egg threatens to "use the boot", he means to take the ring out and use that authority.

So this is not a question of English usage.  It is a question of the plot of the story.

Comment: And here I figured he was threatening to start up his computer.  Or pull a lug wrench out of the trunk of his car.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the book with me anymore, so I can't verify. It was indeed a comic's book (a graphic novel), and I don't remember seeing the Egg's character wearing boots, nor (a fortiori) hiding anything inside. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the story, Egg (the prince) is travelling in disguise, and is disgusted by the coming struggle. In threatening to use his "boot", he is suggesting that he will reveal himself and use his authority as prince to resolve the issue.

So in this case, "boot" is a symbolic reference to power, and is used in the sense that Egg can kick people around until they start behaving properly. The underlying image is that of a superior kicking a subordinate in the butt to get him doing things correctly.

Comment: It is possible indeed to read the expression in that way. Thank you for your answer.